# Compare failure rates across multiple systems

Tags: likelihood, outliers, failure-rate

I work in pharmaceutical manufacturing and one part of a process is a filtration step that uses 'clusters' or 'sets' of single-use (disposable) filters in parallel - the product flows into a manifold and then is distributed evenly between these sets, which are installed in individual housings.

Each of the (seven) sets must be tested individually prior to use (the housing is isolated and cannot be used if it fails) and we want to know if one housing / set is failing the test statistically more than the others.

Each set has been tested for 273 batches and I get the following number of failures / failure rate and suspect that Set #5 is more likely than than the others to fail:

| Set # | Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 | Set 4 | Set 5 | Set 6 | Set 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Failures | 5 | 1 | 3 | 4 | **9** | 2 | 1 |
| Failure rate * | 1.83 | 0.37 | 1.10 | 1.17 | **3.30** | 0.73 | 0.37 |

* Failures per 100 tests

I had considered just looking at the mean & standard deviation failure count and checking for mean +/- 3SD, but as I only have seven sets, the standard deviation is too large (2.82) vs. the mean (3.57)

[image: Column chart of number of failures]

Code in Python (with credit to @dipetkov for the 'R' original):

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([5, 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1])
n = np.repeat(273, 7)

failures = np.sum(x)
successes = np.sum(n) - np.sum(x)
n_rep = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 8), repeats=n)
# Create array of tests outside of the function, for speed
t_rep = np.concatenate((np.ones(failures), np.zeros(successes)))

def one_permutation_under_null():
    x_rep = np.random.choice(t_rep, size=len(n_rep))
    rates = np.array([np.mean(x_rep[n_rep == i]) for i in range(1, 8)])
    # * the highest failure probability
    # return np.max(rates)
    # * the difference between the highest and lowest failure probability
    # return np.max(rates) - np.min(rates)
    # * the difference between the highest probability and the average of the rest
    rates = np.sort(rates)
    return rates[6] - np.mean(rates[:5])

np.random.seed(1234)

s_rep = np.array([one_permutation_under_null() for _ in range(10000)])
# result = np.mean(s_rep >= 9 / 273)
# result = np.mean(s_rep >= 9 / 273 - 1 / 273)
result = np.mean(s_rep >= 9 / 273 - (5 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 1) / (6 * 273))

print(f'Proportion of iterations with statistic equal to or more extreme than the observed result: {result}')
```

Comment: What is a set of filters? Something like a batch and you tested 39 = 273 / 7 different filters from each set/batch, following the same procedure each time?

Comment: Hi @dipetkov, we have seven 'clusters' (sets) of virus filters (pharmaceutical manufacture) working in parallel and each cluster is tested before use.  We have completed 273 manufacturing batches and every set is tested per batch (so actually 273 * 7 = 1911 tests) and not used if it fails the test.

Comment: I still don't understand the setup (it may be clear to others, though). I think it's important to be clear about the number of tests, ie. clear about x failures out of n tests, are the 7 sets supposed to be equivalent, are the same 7 tested repeatedly, etc. If you decide to add more details, please edit the body of your question; it's better not to leave important information in comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updates. Two comments: (a) It's better to report the number of tests; not the failure rate per 100 tests. Unless you ran 100 tests. Knowing the number of test is required to get standard error right. It's one thing to have 2.5% failure rate in 100 tests vs 1000 tests.

Comment: (b) Do you have a minimal success rate that a set must have in order to use it? Then you can test -- for each set separately -- whether it's reliable enough or not. I think this is easier than testing  whether the worst-performing set is worse than the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Failure rate of 2.11 per 100 tests is a lossy summary of the experimental results. What matters is how many failures $x$ were observed out of performing $n$ tests. So report the counts $x$ and $n$. For one, this means no unnecessary rounding, but more importantly, the standard error of the estimated failure probability (aka the failure rate per 100) depends on the size $n$. An estimate of $\hat{p} = 2\%$ in 1,000 tests has smaller standard error than $\hat{p} = 2\%$ in 100 tests.

Now to the question:

> we want to know if one set is failing the test statistically more than the others.

You can test the null hypothesis that the failure rate is the same for all sets with a permutation tests.

The experimental results are:

```r
x <- c(5, 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1)
n <- rep(273, 7)
```

Several statistics could reasonably be formulated to assess if one set fails more often than the others. For example, the highest failure probability [observed to be 9/273 in the data] or the difference between the highest and the lowest failure probability [9/273 - 1/273 in the data] or the difference between the highest failure probability and the mean of the rest [9/273 - (5+1+3+4+2+1)/(6*273) in the data]. The third summary seems closest in spirit to the OP's question, so that's the statistic I use in the permutation test below. (I do the calculations in R.)

So `sum(x) = 25` failures were recorded in `sum(n) = 1911` tests, with 7 sets tested equal number of times. Each iteration of the permutation procedure randomly shuffles a vector of 25 failures (1s) and 1886 = 1911 - 25 successes (0s), and then splits the shuffled vector into 7 sets of 273 elements. Then we compute the statistic of interest from the permuted data. We repeat for N = 10,000 iterations.

```r
failures <- sum(x)
successes <- sum(n - x)
set.id <- rep(1:7, times = n) # The i-th index is the set from which the i-th data point comes from.

one.permutation.under.null <- function() {
  x.rep <- sample(c(rep(1, failures), rep(0, successes))) # Shuffle the observations.
  rates <- tapply(x.rep, set.id, mean) # Break down the observations into sets.

  # We shuffle the observations but keep the mapping between indices and sets fixed.
  # So all permutations of sum(x) failures and sum(n-x) successes into 7 groups
  # of size n1, ..., n7 are equally likely.

  # * the highest failure probability
  # max(rates)
  # * the difference between the highest and lowest failure probability
  # max(rates) - min(rates)
  # * the difference between the highest probability and the average of the other six
  rates <- sort(rates)
  rates[7] - mean(rates[1:6])
}

set.seed(1234)

s.rep <- replicate(10000, one.permutation.under.null())
```

Finally the p-value is the proportion of iterations with statistic equal to or more extreme than the observed one.

```r
# mean(s.rep >= 9 / 273)
# mean(s.rep >= 9 / 273 - 1 / 273)
mean(s.rep >= 9 / 273 - (5 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 1) / (6 * 273))
#> [1] 0.0375
```

Answer (score 2):

I present a second analysis using a Bayesian hierarchical model to estimate the failure probabilities of the seven sets as well as the mean failure probability in the population of sets.

The advantages of the Bayesian approach include:

- We estimate the joint posterior distribution of the failure probabilities, $p_1, \ldots, p_7$, by generating samples $\{ p_i^{(j)} \}$ from the posterior. With that sample, we can estimate the posterior distribution of any function of the $p_i$'s. For comparison with the other answer, I look at the the difference between the failure probability of the 5th set and the average failure probability of the other six sets: $p_5 - (p_1 + \cdots + p_7)/6$.
- We explicitly incorporate domain knowledge and assumptions into the prior. For example, if we have used filters made by the filter manufacturer before, we would have an idea how often their filters fail. Or more generally, based on the literature / previous research, we can make an informed guess what's a reasonable range for the failure probability of a filter of type X or made with material Y and choose a prior that puts most of its probability mass on that range.

Specifically I propose the following hierarchical model for the failure probabilities of $k$ sets: ($X_k$ and $N_k$ are the number of failures and the number of tests, respectively.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_k &\sim \operatorname{binomial}(N_k, p_k) \\
p_k &\sim \operatorname{normal}(\mu_p, \sigma_p)\operatorname{T}[0,1] \\
\mu_p &\sim \operatorname{beta}(1, 24) \\
\sigma_p &\sim \operatorname{student-t}(3, 0, 1)\operatorname{T}[0,]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\operatorname{T}[\text{lower}, \text{upper}]$ indicates the parameter is constrained to the range [lower, upper]. I don't put a constraint on the population mean failure probability, $\mu_p$, as the support of the beta distribution is (0,1); no further restriction is necessary.

I choose a weakly informative student-t prior for the standard deviation, $\sigma_p$. More interesting is the prior for the population mean probability, $\mu_p$. I choose a informative beta prior with mean and standard deviation both equal to 0.04. It's best to specify a prior consistent with domain knowledge but since I lack such knowledge, I go with something that seems reasonable to me: the beta(1,24) distribution gives $\operatorname{Pr}(\mu_p\leq0.05) = .71$ and $\operatorname{Pr}(\mu_p\leq0.1) = .92$.

I fit this model with [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/) using its `cmdstanr` interface; the complete code to reproduce the analysis is attached at the end.

Once we have a sample from the posterior of $\{p_i,\mu_p,\sigma_p\}$ we can explore various aspects of the result. (We should first check the model converges; it does.)

Here are the posteriors of the failure probabilities $\{p_1, \ldots, p_7\}$:

[image]

the posterior of the population mean failure probability $\mu_p$:

[image]

and the posterior distribution of the difference $p_5 - \sum_{i\neq5}p_i/6$:

[image]

The posterior probability that the difference is positive (i.e. set 5 has higher failure probability than the other sets) is 0.927.

*References*

This analysis is inspired by the rat tumor rate example in BDA3. A. Gelman, J. B. Carlin, H. S. Stern, D. B. Dunson, A. Vehtari, and D. B. Rubin. Bayesian Data Analysis. *CRC Press*, 2013. [It's freely available online.](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/)

---

```r
library("bayesplot")
library("cmdstanr")

code <- "
data {
  int K;
  array[K] int X;
  array[K] int N;
}
parameters {
  vector<lower=0, upper=1>[K] p;
  real<lower=0, upper=1> mu_p;
  real<lower=0> sigma_p;
}
model {
  // priors
  mu_p ~ beta(1, 24);
  sigma_p ~ student_t(3, 0, 1);
  
  // Pool the set-specific probabilities towards the population mean probability.
  p ~ normal(mu_p, sigma_p);

  // likelihood
  X ~ binomial(N, p);
}
"

# The experimental results are:
x <- c(5, 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1)
n <- rep(273, 7)

data <- list(K = 7, N = n, X = x)
model <- cmdstan_model(
  write_stan_file(code)
)
fit <- model$sample(
  data = data,
  parallel_chains = 4,
  seed = 1234
)
draws <- as_draws(fit)

mcmc_areas(draws,
           regex_pars = "p\\[.\\]",
           prob = 0.8,
           prob_outer = 0.95,
           point_est = "median"
)

# Calculate the difference between set 5 and the average of the other sets
# *in each posterior sample*
# Then we have a sample from posterior of this derived quantity.
delta.set5.vs.rest <- draws[, , "p[5]"] - (
  draws[, , "p[1]"] + draws[, , "p[2]"]
  + draws[, , "p[3]"] + draws[, , "p[4]"]
  + draws[, , "p[6]"] + draws[, , "p[7]"]) / 6
mcmc_areas(delta.set5.vs.rest)
summarise_draws(delta.set5.vs.rest > 0)

mu_p <- draws[, , "mu_p"]
mcmc_areas(mu_p)
```

Comment: It's wonderful to see the same person provide both a frequentist and a Bayesian answer to a question. (+1)

Comment: Thank you @EdM. And also to ChemEnger for writing an interesting question, with real data.